# What about Flux.jl enables it to be differentiable?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

Reading through some of the Flux.jl docs, I saw this quote:

> Differentiable Programming:
> Existing Julia libraries are differentiable and can be incorporated directly into Flux models.

In the context of Flux and Julia, what does this mean? I understand that Julia and Flux make use of automatic differentiation but how this enables other Julia Libraries to integrate with Flux.jl is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be off here, but isn't this just the usual composability story? I.e. if I have some package `MyPackage` which defines some function `myfun` then I can plug that function into a Flux model and Flux will be able to differentiate through it, assuming that the types of `myfun` aren't too constrained.